# Linear Algebra: Eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find a basis for the corresponding eigenspace to the listed eigenvalue:
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}4&0&1\\-2&1&0\\-2&0&1\end{matrix}\right], \lambda=1$$
This is what I've come up with:
$$\lambda=1:\left[\begin{matrix}4&0&1\\-2&1&0\\-2&0&1\end{matrix}\right]-\left[\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}3&0&1&0\\-2&0&0&0\\-2&0&0&0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&\frac13&0\\-2&0&0&0\\-2&0&0&0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&\frac13&0\\0&0&\frac23&0\\0&0&\frac23&0\end{array}\right]$$
$$x_1=-\frac13x_3$$
$$x_2=0$$
$$x_3=\text{free}$$
Which I would assume would be:$$\left[\begin{matrix}-\frac13\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right]$$ for the basis of $\lambda=1$, assuming that I've done my work correctly, which I'm sure is unlikely.
Now the answer, according to the book, is $$\lambda=1:\left[\begin{matrix}0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right]$$
Could someone explain what I've done wrong? Because I'm not coming out with that answer. Or maybe I am, I just don't know it. Regardless, some help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not $x_3$ that is free and $x_2=0$, it's the other way around.

Comment: Remember, the third column tells you about $ \ x_3 \ . $

Comment: Oh right! Alright yeah, I see why $x_2$ is the free variable. But what about $x_1$?

Comment: @JcE You know what $x_3$, so you can find $x_1$.

Comment: @GitGud, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: You know that $x_3=0$ and $x_1=-\frac13x_3$.

Comment: Yeah, and wouldn't that give me $$\left[\begin{matrix}-\frac13\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right]$$ or something like that?

Comment: @JcE In that vector is $x_3$ equal to $0$?

Comment: @GitGud, well still, I wouldn't be coming out with the same answer as the book, would I?

Comment: @JcE There are infinite possible answers. From $x_3=0$, you can infer $x_1=0$. Since $x_2$ is free, the set of solutions to system is $\color{grey}{\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb R^{3\times 1}\colon x_3=0\land x_1=-\frac 1 3 x_3\right\}=}\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0\\ x_2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\colon x_2\in \mathbb R\right\}$.

Comment: Ooooh, I totally see it now. Haha, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

After you have \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix} 3&0&1\\-2&0&0\\-2&0&0 \end{bmatrix},\end{equation} it is much easier if you reduce to the following: \begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix}3&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.\end{equation} Now since the coefficient of $x_2$ is always $0$, $x_2$ can be any value. And by the second row we have $x_1=0$. But then by the first row $-x_3=3\cdot 0$, so that $x_3=0$.